# Convert a Qt C++ application to a web app

Tags: javascript, c++, mysql

I wrote an application which connects to a MySQL database and queries/adds/deletes data in Qt Framework. I want to convert to a web application run inside a browser. I have some experience in PHP and I could code the whole app in it, but I have a problem: I would be forced to reload the page every time when I want to do something with the database. I want to make something like Facebook/GMail/Facebook Messenger where accessing a database is achieved without reloading the whole page. This is the part which I never done before.

I have some questions about this:

1. What are the JavaScript libraries out there which I could use?
2. What is the appropriate way to do this: create a backend which is between the web app and the database, or connect to the database directly?

I don't necessarily need to stick to that languages, I'm open to new technologies, programming languages.

Edit:
Based on suggestions and my own research I found two technologies which I think I could use: AJAX and PHP(thanks to Hugo Dias) or NodeJS. I didn't wrote any code yet, so which of them would be better for my app? A little more information: this app will used by only the small number of users at the same time, like max 10.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a web server, for eg. Apache Tomcat. If you want to keep your code in c++, you could convert it into a CGI. Otherwise, you can use java servlets or JSP along with JDBC. You can set it up so that when a button is clicked the CGI script is triggered and the database queries are run.

Comment: I don't need to stick to C++. That's why I mentioned JavaScript. Is JavaScript capable for what I need?

Comment: no, javascript is basically client side code, it cannot connect to a database on the server side. for server side programming you need servlets or JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

1. Yes,there are libraries that helps you with that.
   **JQuery** and **PrototypeJS** are some of them.
2. There are some ways of do this, but in any way,you need of a Backend. It's inherent in architecture of Web(Client-Server).

Long answer:

Yes,there are ways of do that. What you're looking for is called AJAX(and stands for **Asynchronous JavaScript and XML**). 
AJAX is a **technics** that gathers some technologies like XHR and Javascript, mainly.

It allows you work with asynchronous requests,what basically lets you update your page without reload it.

You'll find extensive documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) about it,and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp) a simple example with PHP.

The architecture of App is of your choice. Under the Client-Server architecture,you can apply what is best for you,since a monolithic system until a MVC or MVVM pattern.